# How to setup CodeDX plugin for Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a CodeDx sever running at `http://******:82/codedx`

This is how my build task looks in VSTS.
[image]

And these are the logs for the build:
`2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z Task         : Code Dx - Upload Files
2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z Description  : Upload files to Code Dx
2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z Version      : 0.1.18
2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z Author       : CodeDx
2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z Help         : 
2017-11-13T22:17:14.6911243Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-13T22:17:14.7536277Z Preparing task execution handler.
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8474356Z Executing the powershell script: C:\agent\_work\_tasks\CodeDxUploadFilse_7a5fadd7-438e-4e37-bba4-aac9d265893c\0.1.18\UploadSourceToCodeDx.ps1
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Code Dx URL: http://*******:82/codedx
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Project ID: 1
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z API key: **********
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Paths: C:\agent\_work\4\s\***\****\Controllers\AccountController.cs
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Source/binaries filenames: 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Full URL: http://********:82/codedx/api/projects/1/analysis
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Processing C:\agent\_work\4\s\****\****\Controllers\AccountController.cs as file1...
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Reading contents of AccountController.cs...
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Content size: 45983 bytes
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Building HTTP content...
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Building request message...
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z Sending source to Code Dx...
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8630563Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8942973Z Reading response...
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8942973Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8942973Z`

**`2017-11-13T22:17:15.8942973Z Response: {"error":"No appropriate role for file AccountController.cs - it should be removed"}`**

`2017-11-13T22:17:15.8942973Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.8942973Z 
2017-11-13T22:17:15.9411717Z ##[section]Finishing: Code Dx`

How do I specify to scan all my files under a project to CodeDx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload your source code using a zip file. I added two additional tasks to my build definition: 1 to archive the source files into a zip file and 1 to upload the zip file to Code Dx:

[image: Tasks]

The `Archive file to create` parameter of your archive task becomes the `Files to upload` parameter in your Code Dx task.

**Archive task**

[image: Archive task]

**Code Dx task**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer with steps, got it working in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Code Dx accepts application inputs in the following formats ([Built-in Code Scanners](https://codedx.com/Documentation/UserGuide.html#BuiltinCodeScanners)):

1. C/C++ source zip archives
2. Java source zip archives
3. Java bytecode zip archives
4. .Net source zip archives
5. .Net Dlls
6. Ruby on Rails archieves
7. PHP zip archives
8. Python zip archives
9. JavaScript zip archives
10. Scala zip archives

You upload a cs file that is not supported, you can include the source files (e.g. .cs) in a zip file and upload the zip file.